# dataset top n rows in c#

Tags: c#, dataset

I want to select top N rows from a dataset. 
is there any way to do it in C# ?
i dont have access to sql server stored procedures to change them so I need to show only some rows to data bind.

how would I go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using framework 3.5, 
then first get the datatable (dt) and then use the below line -

```
dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

By DataAdapter.Fill Method we can implement Paging in sqlserverce 3.0

```
string Query = "Select * From WorkOrderDetails order by AssetID ASC";

           SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(Query, strConString);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //da.Fill(startIndex, endIndex, dt);

            da.Fill(startIndex, 100, dt);

            dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string Query = "Select * From WorkOrderDetails order by AssetID ASC";
                SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(Query, strConString);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //da.Fill(startIndex, endIndex, dt);
                da.Fill(startIndex, 100, dt);
                dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: This fetches all Data and then only add 100 to the grid. This will kill your performance quiet soon.